# Round up double value in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, rounding

I have a textfield in jasper report as follows :

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$V{v_vcTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

I want to round up this value using HALF_UP rounding mode.Can i achieve this in a simple way.Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I dont want to change my java class. Is there anything i can do in jasper jrxml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify RoundingMode for decimal numbers in Jasper Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899298/how-to-specify-roundingmode-for-decimal-numbers-in-jasper-reports)

Comment: i already checked this question. please refer my edit. checked every related question on SO before posting the question.

Comment: <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[new BigDecimal($V{v_vcTotal}).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).toString()]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: tried this but its not working.can you point out where i am going wrong.

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.5).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN))` - prints *2*  `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.5).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))` - prints *3*. What is wrong?

Comment: Worked now..the problem was that it was somehow taking the old code and generating report..restarting i-report helped. +1 for your answer..thank you.

Comment: @Utkarsh, it would be nice for the community if you accept the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

So all credit to **@utkarsh** their expression is so far the only working one I've seen online that converted my 'double' numbers pulled onto my report, my expression:

```
$f{balance}
```

Would produce doubles from a calculated field in my database like "-1365.00000000003"

In the Expression editor (in lieu of changing it in the source tab) I wanted to pull 2 sig figs from the number for looks. I added this expression and I stopped getting "compilation" errors and the wanted results:

```
new BigDecimal($F{balance}).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).toString()
```

Result would be "-1365.00"

From what I've read this is a bit overkill to get the desired result but I am also under a deadline so I will try to optimize some other time.