# Jasper report : Round variable sum value

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a variable that is the sum of detail values (each value with three decimals).

```
<variable name="montantTtc2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{montantTtc}]]>   </variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

I want, once the sum is done, to round the result to two decimals. (without rounding each detail value to 2 decimals).
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify RoundingMode for decimal numbers in Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899298/how-to-specify-roundingmode-for-decimal-numbers-in-jasper-reports)

Comment: not really, because I need the rounding to be done after the sum is complete

Comment: why don't you just apply pattern when you output it?

Comment: I don't know what the pattern should be if I need to set a rounding mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **pattern** property of textField when you are printing the variable montantTtc2 in your report design. Refer below code snippet

```
<textField pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
  <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$V{montantTtc2}]]>    
  </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```